# how to put a pattern based generic redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 2000+ old URLs like

```
example.com/hello/public/news
example.com/hello/public/notifications
example.com/hello/public/results
```

now I have trimmed `hello/public` this part in the new version

so how do I write a generic redirect in `.htaccess` so if I get hit on these
it redirects to

```
example.com/news
example.com/notifications
example.com/results
```

and more ...

Comment: There are a million and one tutorials online for this. You should at least show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will already have some mod_rewrite directives in your `.htaccess` file, in which case you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive.

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^hello/public/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirect before changing to a 301 (permanent).